# Detecting DOM changes made in browser web console

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, userscripts

A video website that I use has started to overlay an image on top of their content for users using an adblocker. For instance:

[image]

The image is overlaid using the following:

```
<div class="vid_lhs" id="website-name-message-users">
    <img name="Map" usemap="#Map" style="max-width:100%" src="http://drop.website-name.com/website-name/images/website-name-abp-message.jpg">
</div>
```

And the video is hidden by setting `display=none` like so:

```
<div class="vid_lhs" id="ins_videodetail" style="display: none;">
    ....
    <video class="videobase vsc-initialized" id="contentElement" width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto|metadata|none" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" src="http://website-nameod.bc.cdn.bitgravity.com/blah-blah.mp4" data-vscid="blah-blah" autoplay="" style="display: inline; object-fit: fill;"> </video>
    ....
</div>
```

This is easily bypassed using a simple script on the browser's web console:

```
$('#website-name-message-users').remove();
$('#ins_videodetail').show();
```

My question is: **What are the different ways by which the website can identify that the DOM is being tampered, so that they can better protect their content?** I ask because they seem to change the way this adblock-block is implemented every 2-3 days, which leads me to believe that they may be playing a (pointless?) cat-and-mouse-game with users like me...

Comment: it seems to be working against you

Comment: That has to do with an Ad Blocker in the Client's Browser. If they want to see the ads that bad, let them.

Comment: "so that they can better protect their content?". The website doesn't protect anything. Protecting contents in a client-side document  doesn't  even make sense. It just wants to force you to click on ads so it can make _money_.

Comment: @Vohuman true; but they could also do a periodic AJAX poll and stop the video or force close/redirect the page if the DOM was tampered, hence protecting their "content" i.e. block me from watching the video.

Comment: @Vohuman - I don't think they're trying to force anybody to *click* on ads, but they do want the ads to at least be *displayed*. Which seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: @Jedi I'm pretty sure they don't want to drive away clients already scared by all the crap they've already served you.

Comment: For now, I'm not really concerned about the adblock, nor about the business/client relations of the video company. :-) My question is purely on the technical aspect- `how can a website add a check to see if the DOM of a page is tampered in the browser's web console?` @BekimBacaj

Comment: The website probably uses an interval for checking DOM elements.

Comment: @Jedi well, there is a way, a client-side way. But...

Comment: ...yeah, @BekimBacaj understandably, it can't be foolproof/tamperproof.

Comment: @Jedi - yes it can. But it's not polite to say the least.  So, we'll leave it as is...